# Checking for waiting input on standard input

Tags: c++, input, cin

Is there a relatively simple way to check if there is input waiting on standard input in C++? And how do I read it, if there is any?

I'm currently using the following code, but this really is mostly C. I was wondering if there is a better way.

```
#ifdef WIN32
#include "windows.h"
#include "unistd.h"
#else
#include "sys/time.h"
#include "sys/select.h"
#endif

bool input_waiting()
{
#ifndef WIN32

    fd_set readfds;
    struct timeval tv;
    FD_ZERO (&readfds);
    FD_SET (fileno(stdin), &readfds);
    tv.tv_sec=0; tv.tv_usec=0;
    select(16, &readfds, nullptr, nullptr, &tv);

    return (FD_ISSET(fileno(stdin), &readfds));

#else

    static int init = 0, pipe;
    static HANDLE inh;
    DWORD dw;

    if(!init)
    {
        init = 1;
        inh = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
        pipe = !GetConsoleMode(inh, &dw);
        if (!pipe)
        {
            SetConsoleMode(inh, dw & ~(ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT|ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT));
            FlushConsoleInputBuffer(inh);
        }
    }
    if(pipe)
    {
        if (!PeekNamedPipe(inh, NULL, 0, NULL, &dw, NULL)) return 1;
        return dw;
    }
    else
    {
        GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents(inh, &dw);
        return dw <= 1 ? 0 : dw;
    }

#endif
}
```

Update: It's for a chess engine, and this function is called every few thousand nodes to check if the GUI sent a stop/quit command.

Comment: `cin.peek()`, `cin.get()` et al

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Can you be more specific? I'm not taking in any input with std::cin >> x; so there's nothing on the stream to peek. Or am I getting this wrong?

Comment: You may be looking for `cin.readsome()` and/or `cin.rdbuf()->in_avail()`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Looks like it's quite implementation dependent. I tried with std::cin.readsome() and it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `_kbhit()` and `_getch()` from `conio.h` header.

First function returns nonzero value if key was pressed and keystroke is waiting in the buffer. Second one returns that keystroke as character (or, if no key was pressed, locks the thread and waits for keystroke from user).

Here are links to MSDN:

- `_kbhit()`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58w7c94c.aspx
- `_getch()`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/078sfkak.aspx

Comment: There is no 'keystroke'. This is a command sent from another program to standard input.